# Find a match on two excel columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to compare data between two tables on excel and get the cells that match in two columns.
i.e:
Look for the value from cell G9 in column A, if found the check if the value of cell J9 Equals to cell D of the row in which the first match was found.

I tried Vlookup, index and match, but I'm still missing a function to complete the syntax

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(G9,$A$9:$D$1127,1,FALSE),IF(J9=D,"","new"),"new")
```

I don't know what to insert instead of D

Sample: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aJZlpQ2V-bmwmS1Kwk-OIiSvXR552JJH

Comment: Kindly share sample data

Comment: Need to use `Indirect()` function with index and match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MATCH` on an array premises. If you want the number of the line when the values of `G9` and `J9` occur on columns `A:A` and `D:D` simultaneously, use the formula:

```
{=IFERROR(MATCH(J9,IF(A:A=G9,D:D),0),"No Match")}
```

If you want to return just the word "new" in case of a valid match use:

```
{=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(J9,IF(A:A=G9,D:D),0)>0,"new",""),"")}
```

Don't forget to use `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` to place the braces on the formula.

EDIT:

Since I'm having some troubles with showing my solution, I'll be more thorough.
Let's imagine you have the following worksheet:

[image: example]

For each row in the first table, if you want to check a match on the second table, you could place the formula

```
{=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A1,IF(E:E=B1,D:D),0)>0,"new",""),"")}
```

on cell `C1` and drag it to the end (to `C22` on my example). You will get the next result:

[image: example]

Please, don't forget to press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` when you're entering the formula on cell `C1`.

Comment: Ok, i think my diraction is all wrong. I have 2 tables, both with names and month, evrey name appers maximum once each month. I need excel to check if a name&month appears on both tables. do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Do they have to be on the same row? Or you just want to check if they appear anywhere on the table?

Comment: same row. i.e. A1 is jon and B1 is Janury 1st, than look on a row on the second table that contain both.

Comment: You have to adjust the formula I gave you on my answer. If you want to locate `A1` and `B1` values on another table, just change the cells/ranges references on the formula. It's a wonderful method to invest on your `Excel` skills.

Comment: I can`t figure out how to do it for both collums on the same time.

Comment: Unless you be more specific (try to edit your question - maybe by showing us your tables or your data or just a print-screen of your worksheet...), I can't help you anymore! I will wait for your editing...

Comment: I`ve added a sample. i want to check if both Culloms A and B have a match on Collums D and E

Comment: Yes but they have to have a match together. If only one of them have a match to it should give a false

Comment: Try to avoid using whole columns as referenced ranges. It will absolutely ruin the speed in which Excel will process these formulas. Have a look at what I mean by running the evaluate formula.

Comment: thank you that works great! by the way, the first brace need to be before the =

Comment: Ops! Corrected already! Thank you for notice... And I'm glad I could help!